# How to add a link to the typewriter effect in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using the typewriter effect in react, and want to add a link to the second line (where is says "learn more about me") so that when you click it it sends the user to the about me page, but I am confused as to how to do it. I tried using href or onclick but neither work. please help.

```
<Typewriter
  onInit={(typewriter)=> {
  typewriter
  .typeString("Hi")
  .pauseFor(1000)
  .deleteAll()
  .typeString("Learn More about me") 
  .start();
  }}
/>
```

Comment: What is `Typewriter`? If you are using a library, please link its documentation, if not, post your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Change state after `.deleteAll` and render component with an `a` wrapper.

```
const [isLink, setIsLink] = useState(false);
const init = (typewriter)=> {
  typewriter
  .typeString("Hi")
  .pauseFor(1000)
  .deleteAll()
  .callFunction(() => setIsLink(true))
  .typeString("Learn More about me") 
  .start();
}
return (
  isLink
  ? <a href="https://google.com">
    <Typewriter
      onInit={init}
    />
  </a>
  : <Typewriter
    onInit={init}
  />
)
```

Comment: @Bergi thanks, I missed it. Fixed the answer